# Controllers and Views in Spring Framework in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, spring, spring-mvc

I've installed Spring.Net extension for Visual Studio. I couldn't find an example on how to use Controller and Views using Spring Framework in .NET.

If any one can give me the sample project of Web Application using Spring Framework with Controller/Views example ?

Thanks,

FaisalNasir

Answer (score 0):

Check the examples pages [here](http://springframework.net/examples.html) for many examples, also this is the documentation [quick start](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-quickstart.html).

Comment: it didn't contains the controller usage example